# How to use multi-line f-strings when using psycopg2

Tags: python, string, psycopg2

I am trying to use a multi line f-string when using psycopg2, like this:

```
query = (
            f"select tb.id"
            f"from someDB.tableA ta"
            f"inner join someDB.tableB tb on ta.url = tb.fk_url"
            f"where ta.name = '{some_name}'"
            f"and tb.type in ('{some_type}')"
            f"order by tb.id;"
        )
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        cursor.fetchall()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: select tb.idfrom someDB.tableA tainner join someDB.tableB...
```

Any idea on how to use multi line f-strings in psycopg2?
I don't have to use f-strings if standard multi line will work too.
I just prefer it, if possible.

Comment: You have several problems. The first: you don't have spaces between your string literals, so the column and from keyword get lumped together. Buth the bigger problem is that THOUGH SHALT NOT USE STRING FORMATTING FOR SQL QUERIES. Seriously. Don't do it. Use the parametrised form of execute. You open yourself up for SQL injection issues, and also don't benefit from faster statement parsing in the DB etc.

Comment: @deets maybe he's making a hardcoded scheduled report that runs a SQL provided by a customer hence not being subject to a SQL injection. Otherwise I of course agree.

Comment: @reportgunner I would argue that bad habits rarely are applied selectively. There is also other features like using of proper datetime objects and execution planning benefits from always getting the same statement (even if parameters change) by using placeholders. So I would invest into forming the habit of using parametrised execute, instead of justifying exceptions. YMMV of course.

Comment: I tried deleting this question. as I found out it was just my typos. But the system wouldn't let me... But yes as @deets pointed out. I needed a space after each of my string literals. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same like multiline strings, just put an `f` in the front:

```py
>>> foo = 'this is foo'
>>> bar = 'this is bar'
>>> longstring = f"""
... foo value = {foo}
... bar value = {bar}
... """
>>> print(longstring)

foo value = this is foo
bar value = this is bar
```